# Error running Rstudio after install

Tags: windows, r, rstudio

I get the following error message when installing Rstudio:

> "Error installing package: '\corp.corpcommon.com\users\E212\MY Documents'
>   CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
>   UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
>   * installing *source* package 'rstudio' ...
>
> ** R
>
> ** inst
>
> Warning in file.create(to[okay]) :
>
> cannot create file '\corp.corpcommon.com/users/E212/MY Documents/R/win-
>   library/3.1/rstudio/CITATION', reason 'No such file or directory'
>
> ** preparing package for lazy loading
>
> ** help
>
> *** installing help indices
>
> ** building package indices
>
> ** testing if installed package can be loaded
>
> *** arch - i386
>
> *** arch - x64
>
> ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
>   * removing '\corp.corpcommon.com/users/E212/MY Documents/R/win-library/3.1/rstudio'
>
> Error installing package: '\corp.corpcommon.com\users\E212\MY Documents'
>   CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
>   UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
>   * installing *source* package 'manipulate' ...
>
> ** R
>
> ** preparing package for lazy loading
>
> ** help
>
> *** installing help indices
>
> ** building package indices
>
> ** testing if installed package can be loaded
>
> *** arch - i386
>
> *** arch - x64
>
> ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
>   * removing '\corp.corpcommon.com/users/E212/MY Documents/R/win-library/3.1/manipulate'"

Do anyone know what it is, what it means, and how I can fix it?`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try removing the space from your file path `'\corp.corpcommon.com\users\E212\MY Documents'` R doesn't like file paths with space characters in them

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename MY Documents to MYDocuments. so the file path will be '\corp.corpcommon.com\users\E212\MYDocuments'.